# An invertible sparse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I'm not entirely certain about how to tackle this problem.... I hope you ladies and gents can help :)

If $M\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that every row has precisely tow non-zero entries, one is precisely equal to $1$ and the other is found in the diagonal and is strictly greater than one.  Must $M$ be invertible?

### My thoughts to date :)

I believe the answer to be yes; reasoning:
*Intuition*: for $n\leq 2$ $M$ can be readily calculated directly.

*Proof sketch idea:* For arbitrary large $n$, I was thinking using the mini-max theorem to obtain a lower-bound on the smallest eigenvalue; and since all the non-zero entries are sufficiently large (at least 1); I would be done since then all eigenvalues must be strictly positive....
(But is the matrix Hermitian and how can I calculate this explicitly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corollary to Gershgorin's theorem states:

More generally: let $M\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that:
\begin{equation}
(\forall i\in {1,..,n}) (\sum_{j\neq i} a_{i,j}) < a_{i,i}. 
\end{equation}

However, Gershgorin's theorem implies that each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$ satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\lambda \in \cup_{i=1}^n Ball_{(\sum_{j\neq i} a_{i,j})}( a_{i,i}).
\end{equation}
However the first equation implies that $0\notin \cup_{i=1}^n Ball_{(\sum_{j\neq i} a_{i,j})}( a_{i,i})$ and in particular the disc in question lies in the first quadrant of the complex plain.

*Therefore every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$ satisfies: $min\{Re(\lambda),Im(\lambda)\} >0$ and in particular $M$ is in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.*

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.  Apply [Gershgorin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: Thanks I'll post my solution :)

Comment: Very pretty theorem :)

Comment: I agree!  Its one of the coolest an most visual I've every seen in linear algebra :)  Thanks for the link :D